# gradle tests filtering does not work for Parameterized adapter

Tags: gradle, junit, filtering, runner

gradle tests filtering does not work for Parameterized adapter. e.g.,

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
    }

}
```

Run one test method for parameter 1:

```
gradle test --tests com.example.test.FooTest.testFoo[1]
```

works.

But for a runner adapter wrapping over Parameterized.class, it does not work.

```
public class HelloAdapter extends Runner {

    private Runner wrapped;

    public HelloAdapter(Class testClass) {
        this.wrapped = new Parameterized(testClass);               
    }   

    @Override
    public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        wrapped.run(notifier);
    }

}


@RunWith(HelloAdapter.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
    }

}
```

Run one method for parameter 1:

```
gradle test --tests com.example.test.FooTest.testFoo[1]
```

[1] will be ignored. Gradle will run the test for all parameters [0], [1], [2], ...

HelloAdapter can not subclass Parameterized, since it can be adapter of multiple runners.